# Print all combinations of size r from an array of size n

Tags: java, combinations

I want to solve the following problem: given an array of size n, print all combinations of size r. As far as I know combination means that the order does not matter, i.e. `{1, 2}` is the same as `{2, 1}` so we have to deal with repetitions. I tried to solve the problem recursively, but I print the same combination several times. This is my code:

```
//main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int r = 3;
        permute(arr, r);
}

//permute function
private static void permute(int[] arr, int r) {
        int[] res = new int[r];
        doPermute(arr, res, 0, 0, r);
}

//helper function
private static void doPermute(int[] arr, int[] res, int currIndex, int level, int r) {
        if(level == r){
            printArray(res);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = currIndex; i < arr.length; i++) {
            res[level] = arr[currIndex];
            doPermute(arr, res, currIndex+1, level+1, r);
            doPermute(arr, res, currIndex+1, level, r);
        }
    }

//print array function
private static void printArray(int[] res) {
        for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(res[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

And this is part of my very long output:

```
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 4 
1 3 4 
1 3 4 
1 2 3 
1 2 4
```

The code produces all combinations, however with many repetitions. Any help will ge appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my previous answer, I just realized that it was so dumb, that's why I tried somethings for you, try to take off the loop :

```
private static void doPermute(int[] arr, int[] res, int currIndex, int level, int r) {
    if(level == r){
        printArray(res);
        return;
    }
    if(currIndex<arr.length){
        res[level] = arr[currIndex];
        doPermute(arr, res, currIndex+1, level+1, r);
        doPermute(arr, res, currIndex+1, level, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! However the above code again print some combinations several times. I'll try to find the bug.

Comment: Is it better than before  ?

Comment: you can like create an array that will contain the strings you want to print, and take off the repetitions, this may be an odd solution, but if you want to use recursivity, it may be difficult to detect repetition

Comment: It's actually the loop that causes the repetitions, i don't see why yuo're using it.